# React Native, Cannot update a component from inside the function body of a different component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I made a custom react navigation drawer but getting that error (Cannot update a component from inside the function body of a different component.) Anyone know why I'm getting that error?

```
const [progress, setProgress] = React.useState(new Animated.Value(0));
  const scale = Animated.interpolate(progress, {
    inputRange: [0, 1],
    outputRange: [1, 0.8],
  });
  const borderRadius = Animated.interpolate(progress, {
    inputRange: [0, 1],
    outputRange: [1, 15],
  });
  const animatedStyle = {borderRadius, transform: [{scale}]};
.......
 <Drawer.Navigator
          overlayColor="transparent"
          drawerType="slide"
          contentContainerStyle={{flex: 1}}
          drawerContentOptions={{
            activeBackgroundColor: 'transparent',
            activeTintColor: 'white',
            inactiveTintColor: 'white',
          }}
          sceneContainerStyle={{backgroundColor: colors.themeColor}}
          drawerContent={(props) => {
            setProgress(props.progress);
            return <CustomDrawer {...props} />;
          }}
          drawerStyle={{
            flex: 1,
            width: '78%',
            backgroundColor: 'transparent',
          }}>
          <Drawer.Screen name={strings.NAV_HOME}>
            {(props) => <MainStack {...props} style={animatedStyle} />}
          </Drawer.Screen>
        </Drawer.Navigator>
```

If someone know about it please tell me how to solve it please.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that you are declaring the state in a component, and in a child component passed via props you are changing the state with setProgres. React treats this as an alert that would cause possible side effects. To solve this problem, you can use react contexts, which aim to share state between descendent components to your provider.
I solved this problem by creating a context with the state of `progress`. That way I can provide the child components with the state of `progress` and the possibility of changing this state. Here is the implementation I used to resolve the warning:

`drawer.context.tsx`

```
import React, {
  useMemo,
  useState,
  useContext,
  useCallback,
  createContext,
} from 'react'
import Animated from 'react-native-reanimated'

import { AnimatedStyle } from '~/routes/app.routes/stack.navigator'

interface DrawerContextData {
  readonly progress: Animated.Node<number>
  readonly animatedStyle: AnimatedStyle
  readonly changeProgress: (n: Animated.Node<number>) => void
}

const DrawerContext = createContext({} as DrawerContextData)

export const DrawerProvider: React.FC = ({ children }) => {
  const [progress, setProgress] = useState<Animated.Node<number>>(
    new Animated.Value(0),
  )
  const scale = Animated.interpolateNode(progress, {
    inputRange: [0, 1],
    outputRange: [1, 0.8],
  })
  const borderRadius = Animated.interpolateNode(progress, {
    inputRange: [0, 1],
    outputRange: [0, 10],
  })

  const changeProgress = useCallback(
    (n: Animated.Node<number>) => setProgress(n),
    [setProgress],
  )

  const animatedStyle = useMemo(
    () => ({ borderRadius, transform: [{ scale }] }),
    [borderRadius, scale],
  )

  return (
    <DrawerContext.Provider value={{ progress, changeProgress, animatedStyle }}>
      {children}
    </DrawerContext.Provider>
  )
}

export const useDrawer = () => {
  const context = useContext(DrawerContext)
  if (!context) {
    throw new Error('useDrawer must be used with a DrawerProvider')
  }
  return context
}
```

`index.tsx`

```
import React, { useMemo } from 'react'
import { View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native'
import { widthPercentageToDP as wp2dp } from 'react-native-responsive-screen'

import { createDrawerNavigator } from '@react-navigation/drawer'
import { useTheme as useRestyleTheme } from '@shopify/restyle'

import { Drawer as DrawerContent } from '~/components'
import { StackNavigator } from '~/routes/app.routes/stack.navigator'
import { Theme } from '~/themes'

import { useDrawer } from './drawer.context'

const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator()

const styles = (theme: Theme) =>
  StyleSheet.create({
    drawerContainer: {
      flex: 1,
      backgroundColor: theme.colors.drawerNavigationBackground,
    },
    drawerNavigator: {
      flex: 1,
      width: wp2dp('65%'),
      backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    },
  })

export const DrawerNavigator: React.FC = () => {
  const theme = useRestyleTheme<Theme>()
  const { animatedStyle } = useDrawer()
  const style = useMemo(() => styles(theme), [theme])

  return (
    <View style={style.drawerContainer}>
      <Drawer.Navigator
        drawerType="slide"
        overlayColor="transparent"
        drawerStyle={style.drawerNavigator}
        drawerContentOptions={{
          activeBackgroundColor: 'transparent',
          activeTintColor: 'white',
          inactiveTintColor: 'white',
        }}
        sceneContainerStyle={{ backgroundColor: 'transparent' }}
        drawerContent={(props) => {
          return <DrawerContent {...props} />
        }}
      >
        <Drawer.Screen name="App">
          {(props) => <StackNavigator {...props} style={animatedStyle} />}
        </Drawer.Screen>
      </Drawer.Navigator>
    </View>
  )
}
```

do not forget to include with the provider:

```
import React from 'react'

import { DrawerProvider } from '~/routes/app.routes/drawer.navigation/drawer.context'

import { DrawerNavigator } from './drawer.navigation'

export default function AppRoutes() {
  return (
    <DrawerProvider>
      <DrawerNavigator />
    </DrawerProvider>
  )
}
```